# GCM registration step conflicts when using 3rd party library and separate GCM implementation for same app?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am curious to know if there might be any conflicts when using a 3rd party library for push notifications (such as Parse in this case) along side a separate GCM implementation for the same app?

At startup I can see (by routing all broadcasts through the same receiver) that Parse receives a GCM registrationToken ("A") that is different from the registrationToken ("B") I receive when calling `GoogleCloudMessaging.register(SENDER_ID)` for my separate "GCM client implementation". Which is all good as long as I know for sure that Parse doesn't use regToken B somehow (depending on which broadcast message is sent first?).

Can I be sure that `GoogleCloudMessaging.register(SENDER_ID)` only returns the registrationToken connected to my SENDER_ID, and not accidentally to the default sender_id that Parse use for its registration since both registrations are initiated at startup?

Answer (score 1):

Parse's GCM registration process is totally behind the scene. If you use a different sender ID, you might get a different registration ID. You can still use the registration ID for your own server, even Parse uses the same registration ID. From the [GCM official documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html#diffs), it states `Multiple parties can send messages to the same app with one common registration ID.`

---

You do not need to supply a sender ID to Parse for GCM registration. You just need to register the required service and broadcast receivers in your Android manifest file. Please see this link for more information: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

For GCM, it needs sender id, registration id and application id etc to complete the registration process. For more information about GCM registration, please see this link: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#register and this one about the manifest file in GCM: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest

Comment: Actually Parse uses its default sender id to request a GCM registration token: `In particular, the SDK will automatically register your app for push at startup time using Parse's sender ID (1076345567071) and will store the resulting registration ID in the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation.` (from https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android). So at startup 2 registrations for GCM tokens are requested, and my question is: how can I be sure which regToken Parse receives vs which regToken my GCM implementation/client receives? In theory they could get mixed up?